# How to add and display items in a list view group in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

Hello people thank you in advance I am struggling a little bit with trying to add items to a group that is defined in a list view.

The group is the list view is called group1

this is the code I am doing at the moment to add the items to the list but then how do I get them into the group?:

```
                    Dim NormalListView As ListViewItem = uiListview.Items.Add(id)

                    NormalListView.SubItems.Add(value)
                    NormalListView.SubItems.Add(value)
```

This bit above all works but I need to find out how to add this to a group that has been predefined in the UI or a way to implement the group through code so that I can use it to add items to with vb.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListView` will have a collection of Groups, the `ListViewItem` has a `Group` property.  So, set the property like this:

```
myLVI = New ListViewItem()
myLVI.SubItems.Add(...)

myLVI.Group = theListView.Groups("FooBar")

theListView.Items.Add(lvi)
```

Each Group also has its own collection of items which belong to that group, so alternatively, you can do:

```
myLV.Groups("FooBar").Items.Add(lvi)
```

Where "FooBar" is the name of the group you wish to use.